# Using getElementsByTagName to select all divs

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where I can only use JS to manipulate an HTML file. I am wanting to change the background color of all divs within the HTML and I currently have the following.

```
//Highlight Function

function highlight(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function init() {
  //Mouseover
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  divs.addEventListener('mouseover', highlight, false);
  divs.addEventListener('mouseout', unhighlight, false);
}
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Obviously the current code only changes one of the divs, how do get it to select all of the divs by only manipulating the JS

Comment: Why don't do this with CSS?

Comment: `divs` is an array, so just iterate over the array with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Barmar actually it's not really an array, but in this case one can think of it as an array. (It's a NodeList.)

Comment: JQuery $('div'), anyone? Isn't it simple and would be better for future use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

function highlight() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function unhighlight() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
        if (window.addEventListener) { //Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 10
            elm[i].addEventListener('mouseover', highlight, false);
            elm[i].addEventListener('mouseout', unhighlight, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) { //IE < 9
            elm[i].attachEvent('onmouseover', highlight);
            elm[i].attachEvent('onmouseout', unhighlight);
        }
    }
}

    if (window.addEventListener) { //when document is loaded initiate init
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onDOMContentLoaded", init);
    }
```

please note that `addEventListener` is not supported in IE < 9 you have to use `attachEvent` instead

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/zzAcy/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `.addEventLister()` like that - it has to be called element by element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i)
  divs[i].addEventListener(...);
```

Alternatively, you could add a single event listener to the `<body>` element and catch events that bubble up from `<div>` elements.