# Event listeners not working

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to learning Javascript and I need help with adding event listeners.   On team treehouse, I was taught to add a simple event listener like this to change the colour of something when it is clicked on:

```js
var changeColor = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

changeColor.addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeColor.style.color="red";
});
```

This will not work when i run index.html. 
The error is:

Uncaught TypeError: changeColor.addEventListener is not a function at scripts.js:3

I have been attempting to fix this for hours now, but I don't understand where I have gone wrong.

I am using Virtual Studio.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't the best duplicate. This would be better -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661807/document-getelementsbytagname-not-working

Comment: or ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801003/using-getelementsbytagname-to-select-all-divs